# Are there any worse sorting algorithms than Bogosort (a.k.a Monkey Sort)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

My co-workers took me back in time to my University days with a discussion of sorting algorithms this morning.  We reminisced about our favorites like [StupidSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort), and one of us was sure we had seen a sort algorithm that was `O(n!)`.  That got me started looking around for the "worst" sorting algorithms I could find.

We postulated that a completely random sort would be pretty bad (i.e. randomize the elements - is it in order?  no?  randomize again), and I looked around and found out that it's apparently called [BogoSort, or Monkey Sort, or sometimes just Random Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Monkey Sort appears to have a worst case performance of `O(∞)`, a best case performance of `O(n)`, and an average performance of `O(n·n!)`.

What is the currently official accepted sorting algorithm with the worst average sorting performance (and there fore beeing worse than `O(n·n!)`)?

Comment: How many bogomips per bogosort?  Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: To clarify, are you excluding the trivial case where best case performance is O(∞)?

Comment: @tloflin - generally yeah, I assume any named algorithm would have to have a remote chance of success.  I'll clarify the question a bit - are there any algorithms that are worse than n*n! on average?

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MultiplyAndSurrender

Comment: My buttheadsort, detailed below, would be worse than n*(n!^n)!

Comment: I heard that the monkey sort is also known as "drunk man sort", a name that I find much more evocative.

Comment: You can adapt your BogoSort to use a very slow (and even better: erroneous) random generator.

Comment: O(foo) is defined as the worst case time complexity, not a generic performance metric. Best case time complexity is Ω(foo). There is no notation for average time complexity, though Θ(foo) comes close. Not really important to the question, though.

Comment: @Debilski: That will make it a constant factor slower, which is ignored in big-O notation.  For a slower _notation_ I don't think you'll find much.

Comment: @Matteo Italia - or it could be called "Toddler Sort" as anyone with 2 year old can attest.

Comment: UserSort: promt the user to sort the array manually.

Comment: As of 2013, we have https://xkcd.com/1185/

Comment: As of 2019, worstsort is a sorting algorithm, that has a finite end but can be made as inefficient as needed by choosing functions that grow fast on given input numbers. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort#Related_algorithms

Answer (score 481, accepted):

From [David Morgan-Mar](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/)'s Esoteric Algorithms page: **[Intelligent Design Sort](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/intelligentdesignsort.html)**

> **Introduction**
>
> Intelligent design sort is a sorting algorithm based on the theory of
> intelligent design.
>
> **Algorithm Description**
>
> The probability of the original input list being in the exact order
> it's in is 1/(n!). There is such a small likelihood of this that it's
> clearly absurd to say that this happened by chance, so it must have
> been consciously put in that order by an intelligent Sorter. Therefore
> it's safe to assume that it's already optimally Sorted in some way
> that transcends our naïve mortal understanding of "ascending order".
> Any attempt to change that order to conform to our own preconceptions
> would actually make it less sorted.
>
> **Analysis**
>
> This algorithm is constant in time, and sorts the list in-place,
> requiring no additional memory at all. In fact, it doesn't even
> require any of that suspicious technological computer stuff. Praise
> the Sorter!
>
> **Feedback**
>
> Gary Rogers writes:
>
> > Making the sort constant in time
> > denies the power of The Sorter. The
> > Sorter exists outside of time, thus
> > the sort is timeless. To require time
> > to validate the sort diminishes the role
> > of the Sorter. Thus... this particular
> > sort is flawed, and can not be
> > attributed to 'The Sorter'.
>
> Heresy!

Comment: Also known as "Assumption Sort": Assume the list is sorted, return!

Comment: +100 - this answer is made out of 100% pure win.

Comment: Hey! Don't forget "Indecisive Sort" (Also know as "Schrodinger's Sort" or "Quantum Sort"), where the list may or may not be sorted, however checking it will reveal whether or not it is. Here is my sample implementation: `void quantum_sort (void *b, size_t n, size_t s, int (*c)(const void *, const void*)) { if (rand () % 2) qsort (b, n, s, c); }`.

Comment: We should dub this **Candide Sort**: `"This is the best of all posibble worlds because it is the world that is, and so in the best possible world the array would already be sorted!"`

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new sorting overlord. All hail the sorter!

Comment: Turning `doesntNeedToSort;` into `monkeySort;`

Comment: bool intelligent_design_sort( list ){ return false; }

Comment: This answer has a faint whiff of Douglas Adams about it

Answer (score 341):

Many years ago, I invented (but never actually implemented) MiracleSort.

```
Start with an array in memory.
loop:
    Check to see whether it's sorted.
    Yes? We're done.
    No? Wait a while and check again.
end loop
```

Eventually, alpha particles flipping bits in the memory chips should result in a successful sort.

For greater reliability, copy the array to a shielded location, and check potentially sorted arrays against the original.

So how do you check the potentially sorted array against the original?  You just sort each array and check whether they match.  MiracleSort is the obvious algorithm to use for this step.

**EDIT:** Strictly speaking, this is not an algorithm, since it's not guaranteed to terminate. Does "not an algorithm" qualify as "a worse algorithm"?

Comment: I assume one can use cosmic rays to prove correctness of this algorithm.

Comment: What's the big O of this?  `O(2^N)`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't think it actually has a big O.

Comment: There are many algorithms which are not guaranteed to terminate (Bogosort for one). I'm think this algorithm's _average case_ is `O(2^N)`, since each bit in the dataset halves the odds of success each round (but I'm not betting money on being right).  You're right that technically it's big-O-infinity since it may not terminate.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Strictly speaking, if it doesn't terminate it's not an algorithm, according to both what they taught me in college and the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm).

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's interesting, we might have to ask on TheoreticalCompSci or something.  I agree with what you said, but clarify that both this and the bogosort do _eventually_ produce output and terminate at a final state, there simply happens to be no upper bound on the time before that happens.  I think it still qualifies as an algorithm, but I'm less certain.

Comment: The Wikipedia article isn't conclusive. It says "While there is no generally accepted formal definition of 'algorithm,' an informal definition could be 'a set of rules that precisely defines a sequence of operations.'" Given the halting problem, it seems pretty strange to have terminology that requires us to solve it just in order to know what to call something. Also, what would you call the things that don't always terminate or the things that we're not sure if they terminate? That definition creates quite a mess.

Comment: @Olathe: The Halting Problem says we can't determine *for all programs* whether they halt, but there are plenty of programs for which we can make that determination. We *know* Quicksort and Bubblesoft halt, and we know they're algorithms.

Comment: @Olathe Hold on a sec while I clarify the wiki for you.... :P

Comment: There must be some severe misunderstanding from that duck to think that an "algorithm" that consists of waiting for an array to sort itself without doing anything to it has O(2^N).

Comment: "Given the halting problem, it seems pretty strange to have terminology that requires us to solve it just in order to know what to call something." -- Severe abstraction failure. Programs that do or don't halt are programs that do or don't halt regardless of any ability to determine that. "Also, what would you call the things that don't always terminate" -- Severe basic logic failure. Since an algorithm is a procedure that always halts, something that doesn't always halt is a procedure that isn't an algorithm.

Comment: "The Halting Problem says we can't determine for all programs whether they halt" -- it's remarkable how many people don't understand this. Virtually every program ever written by a human being can be shown to halt or not halt. It's just that a program that purportedly determines that for all programs can't determine that for itself, so we know it's not generally possible. This theoretical limit is constantly misapplied.

Answer (score 155):

**[Quantum Bogosort](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/thtx/my_new_favorite_sorting_algorithm/ctkml)**

A sorting algorithm that assumes that the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics is correct:

1. Check that the list is sorted. If not, destroy the universe.

At the conclusion of the algorithm, the list will be sorted in the only universe left standing.
This algorithm takes worst-case Θ(N) and average-case θ(1) time. In fact, the average number of comparisons performed is 2: there's a 50% chance that the universe will be destroyed on the second element, a 25% chance that it'll be destroyed on the third, and so on.

Comment: But time ceases to exist in the universe you just destroyed. So an observer in a universe that you have not yet checked will not be able to tell how much of the algorithm has been executed. Thus, this algorithm always takes O(1) time, since previous universe-destructions don't exist anymore.

Comment: To quote the author of the above algorithm:
On average, the universe is destroyed. It takes only O(1) time to decide to destroy the universe, and (assumption) O(1) time to destroy the universe. (destroyUniverse has all the time in the world, which should be a constant as the universe has no inputs, or else something is really screwed up with our understanding of the univerrse.) Therefore the average case is O(1).
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/thtx/my_new_favorite_sorting_algorithm/ctl3h?context=2

Comment: Isn't it always O(n), since you have to check every element?

Comment: Yes, in the only universe that observes the list sorted, it took O(n) time to execute - how long it took in other universes is irrelevant.

Comment: This algorithm has a much bigger problem, however. Assume that one in 10 billion times you will mistakenly conclude a list is sorted when it's not. There are 20! ways to sort a 20 element list. After the sort, the remaining universes will be the one in which the list was sorted correctly, and the 2.4 million universes in which the algorithm mistakenly concluded the list was sorted correctly. So what you have here is an algorithm for massively magnifying the error rate of a piece of machinery.

Comment: This is obviously the best sorting algorithm, not the worst.

Comment: For an easier-to-implement version, have it use a quantum postdecision device.  That way, if, after we shuffle it we determine that it is not correct, we can have the sorting process terminated _before_ we check if it is sorted.  This ensures that all we need to do is simply check the list after the shuffle, because if our check concluds it isn't sorted, we wouldn't have checked (and we already know for sure that we did check it).  Much easier than destroying the universe (we don't have capable hardware yet).

Comment: You have missed out a crucial first step: 0. Shuffle the list using true randomness.

Comment: Failure to head Beetle's advice may result in all universes being destroyed.

Comment: In "average complexity", the average is taken over all possible inputs, not over all possible universes (unless stated otherwise). So step 1 is O(N) plus the cost of universe destruction, as Brendan Long stated.

Comment: Analyzing the complexity of destroyUniverse() gets tricky: yeah, size of universe is constant (?), but the size of (the representation of) the input list is less than size of universe, because it is contained therein...

Answer (score 69):

Jingle Sort, as described [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbzIbvWsDb0).

You give each value in your list to a different child on Christmas.  Children, being awful human beings, will compare the value of their gifts and sort themselves accordingly.

Answer (score 68):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned sleepsort yet... Or haven't I noticed it? Anyway:

```
#!/bin/bash
function f() {
    sleep "$1"
    echo "$1"
}
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    f "$1" &
    shift
done
wait
```

example usage:

```
./sleepsort.sh 5 3 6 3 6 3 1 4 7
./sleepsort.sh 8864569 7
```

In terms of performance it is terrible (especially the second example). Waiting almost 3.5 months to sort 2 numbers is kinda bad.

Comment: This _appears_ to be an `O(N)` sort, but in truth is constrained by however the OS implements timers.

Comment: Any way you cut it, this is probably exhibits a better growth than bogosort.

Comment: I see a race condition there.

Comment: You can change the `sleep "$1"` to `sleep "0.$(printf "%010d" $1)"` to improve performance markedly. `time ./sleepsort.sh 8864569 7` then runs in 0.009s on my laptop.

Comment: This runs in O(N) complexity (dependent of course on the implementation of the timer), it's a simple bucket sort in different form.

Comment: @SamKellett That requires numbers be no bigger than 10 digits. And there could be something about sub millisecond precision race conditions, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Wow, you've implemented a multi-thread counting sort.

Comment: pseudopolynomial!

Answer (score 57):

I had a lecturer who once suggested generating a random array, checking if it was sorted and then checking if the data was the same as the array to be sorted.

Best case O(N) (first time baby!)
Worst case O(Never)

Comment: More interesting to analyze is the _average case_, which is...?

Comment: As all the best text books say, this is left as an exercise for the reader!

Comment: Mooing Duck: O(sometimes)

Comment: @MooingDuck then we need to know cardinality of element type and distribution used to generate random elements in random arrays.

Comment: The complexity is O(N! * Z^N) where Z is the size of the set of possible values and N is the length of the array.

Comment: @Jakub: I think you forgot the complexity of the comparison step.

Comment: @BenVoigt That'd just be a `+ 2N` (check if sorted = N, check if data is the same = N), and you only need to consider the highest-order term, which is clearly the factorial _times_ the exponential

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Not if you use bogocompare.

Answer (score 54):

There is a sort that's called bogobogosort. First, it checks the first 2 elements, and bogosorts them. Next it checks the first 3, bogosorts them, and so on.

Should the list be out of order at any time, it restarts by bogosorting the first 2 again. Regular bogosort has a average complexity of `O(N!)`, this algorithm has a average complexity of `O(N!1!2!3!...N!)`

**Edit**: To give you an idea of how large this number is, for `20` elements, this algorithm takes an average of `3.930093*10^158` ***years***,well above the proposed heat death of the universe(if it happens) of `10^100` ***years***,

whereas merge sort takes around `.0000004` ***seconds***,
bubble sort `.0000016` ***seconds***,
and bogosort takes `308` ***years***, `139` ***days***, `19` ***hours***, `35` ***minutes***, `22.306` ***seconds***, assuming a year is 365.242 days and a computer does 250,000,000 32 bit integer operations per second.

**Edit2**: This algorithm is not as slow as the "algorithm" miracle sort, which probably, like this sort, will get the computer sucked in the black hole before it successfully sorts 20 elemtnts, but if it did, I would estimate an average  complexity of `2^(32(the number of bits in a 32 bit integer)*N)(the number of elements)*(a number <=10^40)` ***years***,

since gravity speeds up the chips alpha moving, and there are 2^N states, which is `2^640*10^40`, or about `5.783*10^216.762162762` ***years***, though if the list started out sorted, its complexity would only be `O(N)`, faster than merge sort, which is only N log N even at the worst case.

**Edit3**: This algorithm is actually slower than miracle sort as the size gets very big, say 1000, since my algorithm would have a run time of `2.83*10^1175546` ***years***, while the miracle sort algorithm would have a run time of `1.156*10^9657` ***years***.

Comment: great worked answer. sad it doesnt have visibility

Comment: The time includes the fact that alpha particles won't flip any values, because if that is not the case, taking into account the probability of flipping a bit would make this sorting algorithm never ending, and a flip bit occurs almost 96% of times every 3 days in a computer with 4gb of memory ([link](https://www.macobserver.com/columns-opinions/devils-advocate/computer-makers-negligently-ignore-bit-flip-errors) source).

Comment: Oh My God you are a genius!

Answer (score 30):

If you keep the algorithm meaningful in any way, `O(n!)` is the worst upper bound you can achieve.

Since checking each possibility for a permutations of a set to be sorted will take `n!` steps, you can't get any worse than that.

If you're doing more steps than that then the algorithm has no real useful purpose. Not to mention the following simple sorting algorithm with `O(infinity)`:

```
list = someList
while (list not sorted):
    doNothing
```

Comment: But it takes O(n) to check whether it's sorted, so you can get O(n*n!)

Comment: @erikkallen:  Certainly we can come up with an algorithm to verify sortedness that's worse than O(n).  For example, for each element in the array, verify that it's greater than all previous ones, much like insertion sort works.  That's an O(n^2) algorithm, and I'm sure I could come up with worse given a little thought.

Comment: @David Thornley:  the following checking algorithm would perhaps show the same spirit as the bogosort:  pick two random elements, check that the one with the smaller index is smaller or equal to the one with the larger index, then repeat.  Keep a square bit matrix to see which combinations have already been checked.  Of course, checking this matrix could also be done in a random walk...

Answer (score 22):

Bogobogosort. Yes, it's a thing. to Bogobogosort, you Bogosort the first element. Check to see if that one element is sorted. Being one element, it will be. Then you add the second element, and Bogosort those two until it's sorted. Then you add one more element, then Bogosort. Continue adding elements and Bogosorting until you have finally done every element. This was designed never to succeed with any sizable list before the heat death of the universe.

Comment: Holy mother of code. I think we can even do a Bogolplex short.

Answer (score 21):

You should do some research into the exciting field of [Pessimal Algorithms and Simplexity Analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.9158&rep=rep1&type=pdf). These authors work on the problem of developing a sort with a pessimal best-case (your bogosort's best case is Omega(n), while slowsort (see paper) has a non-polynomial best-case time complexity).

Answer (score 17):

Here's 2 sorts I came up with my roommate in college

1) Check the order
2) Maybe a miracle happened, go to 1

and

1) check if it is in order, if not 
2) put each element into a packet and bounce it off a distant server back to yourself. Some of those packets will return in a different order, so go to 1

Comment: The second is almost the equivalent of a bozo sort. First is clever though.

Comment: The first is Miracle Sort.

Answer (score 14):

There's always the Bogobogosort (Bogoception!). It performs Bogosort on increasingly large subsets of the list, and then starts all over again if the list is ever not sorted.

```
for (int n=1; n<sizeof(list); ++n) {
  while (!isInOrder(list, 0, n)) {
    shuffle(list, 0, n);
  }
  if (!isInOrder(list, 0, n+1)) { n=0; }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea that this algorithm is designed to never finish "before the heat death of the universe for any sizeable list"

Answer (score 12):

1 Put your items to be sorted on index cards
 <strike>2 Throw them into the air on a windy day, a mile from your house.</strike>
 2 Throw them into a bonfire and confirm they are completely destroyed.
 3 Check your kitchen floor for the correct ordering.
 4 Repeat if it's not the correct order.

Best case scenerio is O(∞)

**Edit** above based on astute observation by KennyTM.

Comment: No, this is worse because there's no chance of it succeeding.  How would the index cards get into your kitchen?  They're blowing around outside.  It's called, uh, buttheadsort.

Comment: I think he means throw the cards up in the air *outside*, and then check your floor *inside*, where there are guaranteed to be no cards.  Although not a "named" algorithm... it is certainly worse!

Comment: @Patrick Quantum tunneling.

Comment: @KennyTM.  That had actually occurred to me.  *There is an extremely small but non-zero chance that any object might disappear and reappear at any other point in the universe.*  I guess it *could* happen to a thousand index cards . . . Oi.  Dangit, my algorithm is **flawed**.  I'll fix it . . .

Comment: It's kind of like having tea and no tea at the same time. Or space travel using an infinite improbability drive.

Comment: Simpler variant:
1. Add 0 at the end of the list.
2. Check if this resulted in sorting it.
3. If not, repeat (or retry, doesn't matter).

Answer (score 11):

### The "what would you like it to be?" sort

1. Note the system time.
2. Sort using Quicksort (or anything else reasonably sensible), omitting the very last swap.
3. Note the system time.
4. Calculate the required time. Extended precision arithmetic is a requirement.
5. Wait the required time.
6. Perform the last swap.

Not only can it implement any conceivable O(x) value short of infinity, the time taken is provably correct (if you can wait that long).

Answer (score 8):

Nothing can be worse than infinity.

Comment: Infinity + 1.  Jinx, no returns.

Comment: Not for extremely large values of 1  ;)

Comment: Infinity + Infinity = Infinity.

Comment: What really blows my mind about the concept of infinity, is that you can have different "sizes" of infinity.  For example, consider the set of all integers - it is infinite in size.  Now consider the set of all *even* integers - it is also infinite in size, but it is also clearly half the size of the first set.  Both infinite, but different sizes.  So awesome.  The concept of "size" simply fails to work in the context of infinity.

Comment: @zombat: You're talking about cardinality, not infinity as a symbol indicating a trend on the real line / complex plane.

Comment: @zombat.  The size of the set of even integers is the same as the size of the set of the integers, as shown by the fact that you can place them in one-to-one correspondence.  Now, there are more real numbers than integers, as first shown by Cantor.

Comment: And if you *really* want to blow your mind about infinity: http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/02/09/math-puzzle

Comment: Whether \omega + 1 = \omega depends on whether you're doing cardinal or ordinal arithmetic.

Answer (score 6):

**Segments of π**

Assume π contains all possible finite number combinations.
See [math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations)

1. Determine the number of digits needed from the size of the array.
2. Use segments of π places as indexes to determine how to re-order the array. If a segment exceeds the size boundaries for this array, adjust the π decimal offset and start over.
3. Check if the re-ordered array is sorted. If it is woot, else adjust the offset and start over.

Answer (score 5):

Bozo sort is a related algorithm that checks if the list is sorted and, if not, swaps two items at random. It has the same best and worst case performances, but I would intuitively expect the average case to be longer than Bogosort. It's hard to find (or produce) any data on performance of this algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

A worst case performance of O(∞) might not even make it an algorithm according to [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm#Termination).

An algorithm is just a series of steps and you can always do worse by tweaking it a little bit to get the desired output in more steps than it was previously taking. One could purposely put the knowledge of the number of steps taken into the algorithm and make it terminate and produce the correct output only after `X` number of steps have been done. That `X` could very well be of the order of O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n<sup>n!</sup>) or whatever the algorithm desired to do. That would effectively increase its best-case as well as average case bounds.

But your worst-case scenario cannot be topped :)

Answer (score 4):

My favorite slow sorting algorithm is the stooge sort:

```
void stooges(long *begin, long *end) {
   if( (end-begin) <= 1 ) return;
   if( begin[0] < end[-1] ) swap(begin, end-1);
   if( (end-begin) > 1 ) {
      int one_third = (end-begin)/3;
      stooges(begin, end-one_third);
      stooges(begin+one_third, end);
      stooges(begin, end-one_third);
   }
}
```

The worst case complexity is `O(n^(log(3) / log(1.5))) = O(n^2.7095...)`.

Another slow sorting algorithm is actually named slowsort!

```
void slow(long *start, long *end) {
   if( (end-start) <= 1 ) return;
   long *middle = start + (end-start)/2;
   slow(start, middle);
   slow(middle, end);
   if( middle[-1] > end[-1] ) swap(middle-1, end-1);
   slow(start, end-1);
}
```

This one takes `O(n ^ (log n))` in the best case... even slower than stoogesort.

Answer (score 4):

```
Recursive Bogosort (probably still O(n!){
if (list not sorted)
list1 = first half of list.
list 2 = second half of list.
Recursive bogosort (list1);
Recursive bogosort (list2);
list = list1 + list2
while(list not sorted)
    shuffle(list);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Double bogosort

Bogosort twice and compare results (just to be sure it is sorted) if not do it again

Answer (score 2):

This page is a interesting read on the topic: http://home.tiac.net/~cri_d/cri/2001/badsort.html

My personal favorite is Tom Duff's sillysort:

```
/*
 * The time complexity of this thing is O(n^(a log n))
 * for some constant a. This is a multiply and surrender
 * algorithm: one that continues multiplying subproblems
 * as long as possible until their solution can no longer
 * be postponed.
 */
void sillysort(int a[], int i, int j){
        int t, m;
        for(;i!=j;--j){
                m=(i+j)/2;
                sillysort(a, i, m);
                sillysort(a, m+1, j);
                if(a[m]>a[j]){ t=a[m]; a[m]=a[j]; a[j]=t; }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make any sort algorithm slower by running your "is it sorted" step randomly. Something like:

1. Create an array of booleans the same size as the array you're sorting. Set them all to false.
2. Run an iteration of bogosort
3. Pick two random elements.
4. If the two elements are sorted in relation to eachother (i < j && array[i] < array[j]), mark the indexes of both on the boolean array to true. Overwise, start over.
5. Check if all of the booleans in the array are true. If not, go back to 3.
6. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SimpleSort, in theory it runs in `O(-1)` however this is [equivalent to `O(...9999)`](http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/hakmem/hacks.html#item154) which is in turn equivalent to O(∞ - 1), which as it happens is also equivalent to O(∞). Here is my sample implementation:

```
/* element sizes are uneeded, they are assumed */
void
simplesort (const void* begin, const void* end)
{
  for (;;);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One I was just working on involves picking two random points, and if they are in the wrong order, reversing the entire subrange between them. I found the algorithm on http://richardhartersworld.com/cri_d/cri/2001/badsort.html, which  says  that the average case is  is probably somewhere around O(n^3) or O(n^2 log n) (he's not really sure).

I think it might be possible to do it more efficiently, because I think it might be possible to do the reversal operation in O(1) time.

Actually, I just realized that doing that would make the whole thing I say maybe because I just realized that the data structure I had in mind would put accessing the random elements at O(log n) and determining if it needs reversing at O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Randomsubsetsort.

Given an array of n elements, choose each element with probability 1/n, randomize these elements, and check if the array is sorted. Repeat until sorted.

Expected time is left as an exercise for the reader.